# Which Agent-Based framework for Java is preferable?

Tags: java, javaagents, agents-jade

I am researching agent based frameworks for Java and want one that is simple and easy to implement.  Google search uncovered jade, wade, and jac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have experience with Jade and it is a powerful Agent-Based framework with a decent user interface and has active community using and maintaining it.

From the website description, Wade seems to be a layer over Jade that supports Workflows so it is not a replacement but a complement.

Also, take a look at [Jadex](http://www.activecomponents.org) it implements advanced concepts than Jade e.g. mentalistic but still compatible with Jade to some extent.